# JS Pattern & Writing style

Tags: javascript

I currently need some advice regarding the best practices and whether this is code is valid from a review perspective.

Needs some tips of what i should be writing like and whether there are any clear pointers on how i can improve.

```
var Structure = function () {
    var _this = this;
    this.Version = "1.0";

    this.GetDataFromCache = function (relatedNewsRequest) {
        _this.listRequest = _this.SetDefaultsProperties(relatedNewsRequest);
        return Product.AddIn.Cache.Get(Product.Digispace.SiteContext.WebId + _this.GetCacheKey());
    };

    this.GetCacheInterval = function () {
        var validCacheInterval =
            typeof (_this.listRequest.CacheInterval !== "undefined") && _this.listRequest.CacheInterval !== null && !isNaN(_this.listRequest.CacheInterval);
        if (validCacheInterval) {
            if (_this.listRequest.CacheInterval === -1) {
                return Product.Digispace.ConfigurationContext.CachingStrategyInterval;
            }
            else {
                return parseInt(_this.listRequest.CacheInterval);
            }
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    };

    this.GetCacheKey = function () {
        return Product.Digispace.ConfigurationContext.getCacheKey(_this.listRequest.SenderId);
    };

    this.GetPropertyValue = function (requestIn, key, defaultValue) {
        var propertyValue = "";
        for (var prop in requestIn) {
            if (key.toLowerCase() === prop.toLowerCase()) {
                propertyValue = requestIn[prop];
                break;
            }
        }
        return (propertyValue === undefined || propertyValue.toString().trim() === "") ? defaultValue : propertyValue;
    };

    this.SetDefaultsProperties = function (requestIn) {
        var requestOut = requestIn;
        requestOut.SenderId = _this.GetPropertyValue(requestIn, "id", "");
        requestOut.rootWeb = _this.GetPropertyValue(requestIn, "isroot", true);
        requestOut.selectFields = _this.GetPropertyValue(requestIn, "selectfields", "ID,Title,TOImage,TOLink");
        requestOut.viewXml = _this.GetPropertyValue(requestIn, "viewxml",
            `<View>
                <Query>
                    <OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy>
                </Query>
            </View>`);

        return requestOut;
    };

    this.Init = function (properties) {
        _this.listRequest = _this.SetDefaultsProperties(properties);
        _this.listRequest.EditMode = Product.AddIn.Utilities.getEditMode();
        _this.listRequest.listControl = _this;
        window["Example.Widgets.Structure.GetLandingItems"] = _this.GetLandingItems;
        _this.Prerender();
        var control = new Product.AddIn.GenericListControlWidget();
        control.Init(_this.listRequest);
        _this.listControl = control;
    };

    this.Prerender = function () {
        Product.Digispace.AppPart.Eventing.Subscribe('/widget/updated/', _this.RefreshWidget, _this.listRequest.SenderId);
    };

    this.Render = function () {
        _this.listControl.Render();
    };

    this.RefreshWidget = function (newProps) {
        if (newProps.id === _this.listRequest.id) {
            newProps = _this.SetDefaultsProperties(newProps);
            var control = new Product.AddIn.GenericListControlWidget();
            control.Init(newProps);
            _this.listControl = control;
            _this.Render();
        }
    };

    this.GetLandingItems = function (data) {
        var dataItem, newItem, newData = {}, itemList = [], id = _this.listRequest.id;
        if (id === '12312-213123-513dasd') {
            newData.Header = 'Corporate Teams';
        } else {
            newData.Header = 'Structure';
        }

        try {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Items.length; i++) {
                dataItem = data.Items[i];
                newItem = {
                    Name: dataItem.Title,
                    Url: dataItem.TOLink ? dataItem.TOLink.get_url() : '',
                    Image: dataItem.TOImage ? dataItem.TOImage.get_url() : ''
                };
                itemList.push(newItem);
            }
            newData.Items = itemList;
            newData.HasItems = newData.Items.length > 0 ? true : false;
            return newData;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };
};

module.exports = Structure;
```

Comment: What version of Node are you using?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Comment: **Lacks concrete context:** Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with sufficient context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Pseudocode, stub code, hypothetical code, obfuscated code, and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**(Potential) Mistakes**

```
typeof (_this.listRequest.CacheInterval !== "undefined")
```

This is not syntactically wrong, but it's not going to work the way you intended. This is going to return the type of the expression `(_this.listRequest.CacheInterval !== "undefined")`, which is of course a boolean. Therefore, the value of the expression `typeof (_this.listRequest.CacheInterval !== "undefined")` will always be the string `'boolean'`, which is a truthy value, so this condition will always evaluate as true and fail in its purpose as a short-circuit. You can just leave out the brackets:

```
typeof _this.listRequest.CacheInterval !== "undefined"
```

Or, in the case of `undefined`, you can write it even more simply:

```
_this.listRequest.CacheInterval !== undefined
```

Also, there's this line:

```
window["Example.Widgets.Structure.GetLandingItems"] = _this.GetLandingItems;
```

Again, this isn't wrong, but I think this isn't what you meant. If you want to access this property later, you'll be able to it with `window["Example.Widgets.Structure.GetLandingItems"]`, but not `window.Example.Widgets.Structure.GetLandingItems`. I.e. this line will create a property on the `window` object with a very long name, and not a property on the `Structure` object called `GetLandingItems`.

If you want to use that line to define a static method on the class of your object, you can use the `constructor` property, which is available on all objects and refers to the constructor function:

```
this.constructor.GetLandingItems = _this.GetLandingItems;
```

**Class declaration**

The first thing I'd recommend is to read up on ES6 class syntax, which is the preferred way of declaring classes these days.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

```
class Structure {
    constructor() {
        this.version = '1.0';
    }

    getDataFromCache(request) {
        // ...etc.
    }
}
```

Note however that this syntax still does not introduce private class members, and it doesn't make it possible to use a closure like you did. There's already a proposal in progress to introduce member visibility in JavaScript, but until then you might want to consider using TypeScript if you need that kind of control.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/

This is all completely optional though; functionally, your code looks good.

**Style**

These are just very minor things, but if you're going to work together with other JS developers, they will probably come up at some point.

- We start method and member names with lowercase letters: `getDataFromCache()`, `this.cacheInterval`, etc.
- We always delimit strings with single quotes `'`. Right now you're mixing single and double.

If you're using an editor such as VSCode, you can download a plugin called ESLint that marks all the style mistakes in your code.

https://code.visualstudio.com/

Hope that helps.

Comment: And you can find really good style guides (the most widely adopted from javascript community) here : https://github.com/airbnb/javascript